# How to compare two collection of array and show in different tab?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

This is my collection result

```
//database data
    Collection {#1526 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:14 [▼
      "item_code" => "Albatrs001"
      "product_name" => "CHILLED SALMON WHOLE (CTNx2NOS/4-5KG FILLETS & Trimmings3KG) "
      "description" => "abc"
      "category" => "Seafood"
      "input_tax" => "ZP"
      "output_tax" => "ZRL"
      "sla" => 5.0
      "threshold_day" => 5.0
      "threshold_max_qty" => 0.0
      "order_limit" => 9.0
      "reference_qty" => null
      "reference_expiry_date" => "5"
      "default_unit_price" => 48.0
      "default_uom" => "KG"
    ]
    1 => array:14 [▼
      "item_code" => "Albatrs002"
      "product_name" => "SMOKED SALMON WHOLE /PKT "
      "description" => "cdf"
      "category" => "Seafood"
      "input_tax" => "TX"
      "output_tax" => "SR"
      "sla" => 5.0
      "threshold_day" => 5.0
      "threshold_max_qty" => 0.0
      "order_limit" => 4.0
      "reference_qty" => null
      "reference_expiry_date" => "5"
      "default_unit_price" => 80.0
      "default_uom" => "PKT"
    ]
  ]
}

//excel data


 Collection {#1526 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:14 [▼
      "item_code" => "Albatrs001"
      "product_name" => "CHILLED SALMON WHOLE (CTNx2NOS/4-5KG FILLETS & Trimmings3KG) "
      "description" => "abc"
      "category" => "Seafood"
      "input_tax" => "ZP"
      "output_tax" => "ZRL"
      "sla" => 5.0
      "threshold_day" => 5.0
      "threshold_max_qty" => 0.0
      "order_limit" => 9.0
      "reference_qty" => null
      "reference_expiry_date" => "5"
      "default_unit_price" => 48.0
      "default_uom" => "KG"
    ]
    1 => array:14 [▼
      "item_code" => "Albatrs002"
      "product_name" => "SMOKED SALMON WHOLE /BAG "
      "description" => "ggg"
      "category" => "Seafood"
      "input_tax" => "TX"
      "output_tax" => "SR"
      "sla" => 5.0
      "threshold_day" => 5.0
      "threshold_max_qty" => 0.0
      "order_limit" => 4.0
      "reference_qty" => null
      "reference_expiry_date" => "5"
      "default_unit_price" => 80.0
      "default_uom" => "PKT"
    ]
    2 => array:14 [▼
          "item_code" => "Albatrs003"
          "product_name" => "ABCDEFG "
          "description" => "cccc"
          "category" => "dddd"
          "input_tax" => "TX"
          "output_tax" => "SR"
          "sla" => 5.0
          "threshold_day" => 5.0
          "threshold_max_qty" => 0.0
          "order_limit" => 4.0
          "reference_qty" => null
          "reference_expiry_date" => "5"
          "default_unit_price" => 80.0
          "default_uom" => "PKT"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to compare both collection and show the new record and changes in tab. I have two tabs to show new and changes record. I will only show new and record that made changes.

I am using nested loop to compare and highlight the changes, but is there any method to show only new and record that made changes and assign them to different tab?

```
// want to compare
$reader = \Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'))->toArray(); 
$result = DB::table('items')->select('....')->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried diff()? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-diff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working solution based on given arrays:

```
$db = array_map('serialize', $db);
$excel = array_map('serialize', $excel);
$diff = array_map('unserialize', array_diff($excel, $db));
```

So, you serialize arrays. You get an array of strings (serialized arrays). Then you use `array_diff` to compare these strings. Then you just unserialize results. In the end, you're getting an array.

Comment: i get this error 'Call to a member function diffAssoc() on array'

Comment: @Crazy well, you've said it's a collection. If you get a collection and then transform it to an array, remove the `toArray()` part. If it's an array from the beginning, try to wrap it to collection with `collect($array)` or use [`arrat_diff_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) instead.

Comment: Yea, one of it is return as array $reader = \Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'))->toArray(); , i tried your method but it returns me Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @Crazy if there is a way for you to share a piece fo the original collection, please do. Then I'll be able to give you a working solution.

Comment: $reader = \Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'))->toArray();  $result = DB::table('items')->select('....')->get();  i want to compare $result and $reader.

Comment: @Crazy I meant raw data to play with (real arrays).

Comment: @Crazy it looks like modified one, because each `array:22` shows just one element.

Comment: already update the array, the excel data i already use collect().

Comment: @Crazy and how you want to compare records? By `item_code`? Or by all properties?

Comment: By all properties.

Comment: @Crazy I've added the simplest solution I've found. I've used arrays and not collections. The results of this will be a new array with 2nd and 3rd arrays. 3rd is a new one and 2nd was changed if you compare it with the original.

Comment: @Crazy so, does it works for you? I've tested and it works just fine with given arrays.

Comment: I tried, it returned all result for me included the record that does not made changes.

Comment: @Crazy well, I only could test it on arrays you gave me and it works for the data.

Comment: If it worked, how can i determine which is new record and existing record? by looping? e.g item code is null then loop into new record tab else to existing record tab?

Comment: @Crazy you can loop over it `foreach ($diff as $item) { }`